# Rails turning select to checkbox acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I have the following select form which works. I want to turn it into a checkbox. I've tried it for a while but to no avail. I'd appreciate your help

```
<%= f.select :tag_list, Artist.tag_counts_on(:tag), {}, {:multiple => true, :class => "tags-select", selected: :tag_list } %>
```

Comment: Have a look at [collection_check_boxes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like below should do

```
<% Artist.tag_counts_on(:tag).each do |some_value| %>
  <%= f.check_box(:tag_list, { :multiple => true }, some_value, nil) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm trying to nest it inside a label but it's not displaying the name. Any idea why?      `<% Artist.tag_counts_on(:tags).each do |tag| %>
    <%= f.label :tag_list, tag.name do %>
      <%= f.check_box(:tag_list, { :multiple => true }, tag, nil) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>`

Comment: @Ray Just try `<% Artist.tag_counts_on(:tags).each do |tag| %> <%= f.label :tag_list, tag.name %> <%= f.check_box(:tag_list, { :multiple => true }, tag, nil) %> <% end %>`

Comment: I want to be able to click on name to select aswell. The above code works but doesn't do that

Comment: Actually don't worry I made it work thnx anyways `<% Artist.tag_counts_on(:tags).each do |tag| %>
    <label>
      <%= f.check_box(:tag_list, { :multiple => true }, tag, nil) %>
      <span class="tag-name"><%= tag.name %></span>
    </label>
  <% end %>`